# VS 2008 Solution Auto checks out everytime

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, team-explorer

We are using "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer Version 9.0.21022.8"

Whenever i open the solution, try to build or try to get latest team explorer automatically checks out the solution.

When i try to check-in displays that files are identical and check-in undone by server.

what is the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search on solution files i found that one of our colleague connected TFS with its name rahter than using IP. We make all TFS connections same and problem is solve.

P.S: This applies also other version of visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to prevent accidental check outs seems to be to change your settings:

> -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Checked-in item
>   Behaviour: Prompt for check-out

Visual studio will still try to checkout files but you won't accidentally check out files any more.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
but this behavior will still be very annoying :D
There must be another solution. Or we must find the reason of this behaviour.